# Unable to create a notebook instance on Amazon SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to create a notebook instance, but I'm getting the following error:

```
AccessDeniedException
User: arn:was:...::......:user/{MY_USERNAME} is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:ListNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigs because no identity-based policy allows the sagemaker:ListNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigs action
```

How to resolve it? Is this a permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is a permissions issue. Please give your role sagemaker:ListNotebookInstanceLifecycleConfigs permission and try.